# Не получается спарсить даннные

Tags: python, bs4

Я новичок. Подскажите, пожалуйста, с помощью какого инструмента можно спарсить данные, которые отдаются на этом сайте? https://honeypot.is/?address=0xdde3ed0bb77c1cafabf8b38f9a1e81edddc7ddc9 . Интересуют BUY TAX, SELL TAX, TRANSFER TAX значения. Я попробовал через BS4:

```
r = requests.get('https://honeypot.is/?address=0xdde3ed0bb77c1cafabf8b38f9a1e81edddc7ddc9').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'lxml')
block = soup.find('div', id= 'hp_info_box')
print(block)
```

Но блок, в котором содержатся все другие блоки и классы находится почему-то пустым:
`block = <div id="hp_info_box"></div>`.
Хотя если смотреть исходный код страницы - в нем много чего есть, включая информацию, которая мне нужна. Заранее благодарю!

Comment: Это динамически подгружаемые данные поэтому можно использовать к примеру selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А если смотреть исходный код правильно, то блок пустой:

[image: скриншот]

Открывай devtools (или fiddler - там поиск удобнее) и смотри, из какого апи берутся данные, после чего посылай запрос туда. Может понадобиться ещё с куками похимичить.